# Is injectivity of a set to its hereditary size set preserved in this relative constructible model of ZF-Reg.?

Tags: set-theory

Quoting from this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309562/can-cardinality-be-defined-with-essentially-no-practical-restriction-on-non-well?answertab=active#tab-top):

"we can build the $L$-hierarchy on any "starting set" of Quine atoms $A$ - let $L^A_0=A$, $L^A_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} L^A_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit, and $L^A_{\alpha+1}=L^A_\alpha\cup\mathcal{P}_{def}(L^A_\alpha)$. Letting $W_A$ be the $L$-hierarchy on $A$ continued until we get a model of ZF-Reg, we can show that the pure part of $W_A$ is countable regardless of whether $A$ is; now simply take an uncountable set of Quine atoms".

So according to this, the set $A$ is not subnumreous to any well founded set.

Now from this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371835/can-we-have-such-an-ill-founded-model-of-zf-reg?answertab=active#tab-top), the Hartog of the set $A$ of all Quine atoms would be incomparable with it!

So existence of this model proves the consistency of failure of choice with $\sf ZF$-$\sf Foundation$. And a similar argument can prove it for $\sf ZF^{collection}$-$\sf Extensionality$.

> My question is about that model, is it the case that the following statement is still preserved in it? $$\forall x (x \hookrightarrow \mathcal H_{|x|})$$

In English: all sets are subnumerous to their hereditarily size sets.

Where $\hookrightarrow$ signify "is injective to"; and $\mathcal H_{|x|}$ denote the set of all sets hereditarily strictly subnumerous to $x$.

Which is a theorem of ZFC.